# What is the most effecient way to keep track of collisions 

Tags: python

I am a new young programmer and I am learning python. I am just making a sample program to learn how to make bigger programs.

```
class Robot():

    def __init__(self):
        self.xpos = 0
        self.ypos = 0

    def step(self, axis):
        print "step"
        if axis in "xX":
            self.xpos += 1
        elif axis in "yY":
            self.ypos += 1

    def walk(self, axis, steps=2):
        for i in range(steps):
            self.step(axis)

    def get_pos(self):
        print "X:%i  Y:%i" % (self.xpos, self.ypos)


robot = Robot()
robot.walk("x", steps=3)
```

All this does is keep track of where an individual robot is. How can i keep track if i have two robots and if they are in the same location.

Example:

```
robot1 = Robot()
robot2 = Robot()
robot1.walk("x",5)
robot2.walk("x",5)
```

they would be in the same location so how would i check to see if any robots are in the same location?

Comment: This is often done using trees to partition the space in which the objects exist, so that you can more-efficiently look for collisions. See: [quadtrees (2d)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) and [octrees (3d)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree).

Comment: i saw those at the end of my book but i havent gotten that far yet. I thought i would just have to incriment array on __init__ and track it that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a class like `Map`, it is simple to write a method that checks the location of all robots:

```
class Map:
    def __init__(self):
        self.robots = []

    def add_robot(self, robot):
        self.robots.add(robot)

    def is_occupied(self, x, y):
        for r in self.robots:
            if r.xpos == x and r.ypos == y:
                return True
        return False
```

This has the advantage of allowing many other operations you might want to perform on the map- you can tell if the path is clear, for example.

Incidentally, you might want to include a reference on each Robot a reference to the Map that it's on (which can be set by the `add_robot` method, so that the robot can tell whether its movement is possible when you call its `move` method.

Comment: this is what i was looking for. I was hoping to make a 2D array to simulate land with obsticles and the program says that when you move if you are getting hotter or coler to a specific location. Thank you so much!

Comment: ETA: Disregard last comment :-)

Comment: That's O(N) though for a simple collision check, while just using a hashmap with the right hash and equals functions would work in O(1). Depends on the usecase and how many robots we're talking about though. For say less than 10.000 that's no problem :)

Comment: @Voo: In that case you would need a dict to go from a robot to its position *and* a set with the locations of all robots, which is indeed premature optimization until we know how many robots there are

Comment: @David Since that's a design decision it's not *premature* optimization since changing such a basic data structure later on can get quite work intense. But yes it depends on the number of robots whether an O(N) solution is problematic or not (we can go by with a single hashset though) - in the end there are lots of data structures for this with their pros and cons. The conventional choice would be a QuadTree though.

Comment: I disagree. If the algorithm for checking and storing the position is restricted to methods of Map (as it should be), it would just be a matter of rewriting those, which is hardly more difficult than writing them in the first place. (What's more, I partly meant premature optimization in that we on SO don't know the details of the problem)

Answer (score 3):

I think you need another class like Room() or CoordinateSystem() or something that holds references to all Robot objects.  Then you can have a class method on say Room, occupied, which returns whether that location is occupied.

Answer (score 0):

While creating a container to hold all your robots' information is certainly one way to check for collisions, the underlying check you'd still have to do is to do equality tests on each robots (x,y).

So at its most simple form, you can do a check by simple AND'ed equality tests and then creating a function to house it:

```
def check_collision(r1, r2):
    if r1.x == r2.x and r1.y == r2.y:
        return True
    return False
```

Such a function could then be modified of sorts to either add to the robot class or to your new map/room class.